# syntax error (missing operator) in sql query expression

Tags: c#, sql, database, syntax, textbox

```
try
        {

            string Query = "SELECT Registrations list FROM [Records] WHERE textBox = '" + comboBox.SelectedValue + "'";
            OleDbConnection me = new OleDbConnection(connection);
            OleDbCommand constr = new OleDbCommand(Query, me);
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            connection.Open();
            reader = constr.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                OleDbParameter parameter = constr.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Registrations list", OleDbType.Integer));
                textBox.Text = reader["Registrations list"].ToString();
            }
            me.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Im trying to get database values to display in textbox but keep getting the error, i've tried mostly everything possible

Comment: what is `Registrations list`

Comment: Have you tried executing the SQL command as-is to see if you can reproduce the error? That may lead you to what is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes but nothing seems to work

Comment: Can you post the schema for the table? The problem seems to be with how you are referencing the column in your `SELECT`.

Comment: can you add the stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 1):

wrap the column name with square brackets

```
SELECT [Registrations list] FROM [Records] WHERE textBox
```

Otherwise sql server looks for a column called `Registrations` and then tries to alias it as `[List]`

Comment: @Johnugo:- Can you tell us the exact error which you are getting when you execute the above query?

Comment: you need to do it in the select query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the column name in square brackets.

```
SELECT [Registrations list]
```

If the column names contais space  then you need to enclose the column name in square brackets else SQL Server will consider it as two column names and since comma will also be not present hence it will give you syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is an error in the SQL

```
string Query = "SELECT Registrations list FROM [Records] WHERE textBox = '" + comboBox.SelectedValue + "'";
```

Between `SELECT` and `FROM` there should be a comma separated list of columns belinging to the table `Records`. If you want to label the column place the keyword `as` between the column name and uts label.

If you placed a white space in the column name (never saw, never did, don't even know if it's possible at all), try including the column name between single quotes. Or (much better) rename the column.